# After adding the selenium driver and chrome driver neither the module nor class path

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried numerous times to add external jars for the Selenium WebDriver and Chrome Driver, but despite adding the paths in the configuration file, neither the module nor the class path. I am encountering the following issues

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

```
    WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

    at Allseleniumproject/NewProject.newPro.main(newPro.java:12)
```

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class newPro {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "C:\\Users\\sures\\eclipse-workspace\\Allseleniumproject\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    }
```